# Aggregate rows based on other table information

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sas

I am looking for a way to re-aggregate some rows, with the given aggregation information from another table.

- I have 1 table with detailed information: tickets with SKUs
- Another table gives a composition of groups of SKUs, that were actually sold together (i.e. a pack of SKU)
- I would like to turn my detailed tickets table by identifying the SKU groups within each ticket, and when possible, merge all SKUs belonging to the same pack into 1 line with the id/name of the pack

Here is the detailed tickets table:

```
ticket_id   SKU     qty
1           A           1
1           B           2
1           C           1
1           D           1
1           E           1
2           F           1
2           G           2
2           B           1
2           H           2
```

Here is the Packs composition table:

```
group_id    SKU     SKU_qty
A1          A       1
A1          B       2
A1          C       1
A1          D       1
B2          F       1
B2          G       2
B2          B       1
```

From the detailed ticket table, we can see that:

- ticket 1 has actually a A1 group of SKU
- ticket 2 has B2

So the resulting table after merging all packs sku into 1 line would give:

```
ticket_id   SKU     qty
1           A1          1
1           E           1
2           B2          1
2           H           2
```

Tickets can have other SKUs - not part of any pack; same SKU can be found in multiple packs.

Multiple languages are available (SQL, SAS or R), but my first "shot" would be to try SQL.

I really don't know from where to start... thanks in advance

Comment: Your example data is really confusing to me. It's hard to understand the problem you are trying to solve, how those tables are related and how your final table can be derived from the other two. Can you explain your examples a bit further?

Comment: @OliverFrost Edited with additional information

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

```
SELECT ticket_id, 
       case when sku is null then sku1 else group_id end group_id,
       qty
FROM(
    select ticket_id, group_id, g.sku, d.sku sku1, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_id) row_num,
           qty
    from detail d 
    left join grouping_ g 
     on d.SKU = g.SKU
    order by ticket_id, D.sku)T1
WHERE sku IS NULL OR row_num = 1;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/RCFEWG27739)

Below is the output I got,

[image]

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: I have no idea how you worked that out from the examples given, but if it's correct then kudos!

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain the principles of your query, in order to understand why it seems to work?